# Unity Add mp3 file from persistentDataPath

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

need your help with turn on mp3 file(with wav and ogg file all is ok) from persistentDataPath in Unity.
I have this code to find audio file in persistentDataPath and turn on as AudioClip

```
public void StartAudio()
{
    StartCoroutine(PlayAudioClip());
}

IEnumerator PlayAudioClip()
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "_song", AudioType.MPEG);
    yield return www.Send();
    //WWW testrequest = new WWW(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "_song.mp3");
    if (www.isNetworkError)
        Debug.Log("play error: " + www.error);
    else
    {
        AudioClip audioTrack = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
        audio.clip = audioTrack;
        audio.Play();
    }
}
```

But when I tried to turn on mp3 file I had this error

> Streaming of 'mpeg' on this platform is not supported
>   UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerAudioClip:GetContent(UnityWebRequest)

Comment: well `Streaming of 'mpeg' on this platform is not supported` ... if it is not supported than use another format which is

Comment: actually, i think about it, but in real I need to use .mp3

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Unity to `2020.1.14f1` and above should play mp3 audio clips. [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1532988/unitywebrequestmultimedia-to-get-audioclip-from-ap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I googled for some more time and founded this [q-a](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1532988/unitywebrequestmultimedia-to-get-audioclip-from-ap.html), so it is really unreal -(